# redhat 7.7 nohz_full dynamic tickless behaviour

Tags: kernel, interrupt, irq

I'm trying to set dynamic tickless behaviour on certain cores (cores 2 - 11), moving all timekeeping to the only unspecified cores (cores 0-1). However, when I perform the instructions specified in:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-cpu-configuration_suggestions#sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Configuration_suggestions-Configuring_kernel_tick_time

While I see approx 2000 ticks per second in core 1, on cores 2-11, I still see approx 150 ticks per second, whereas I should be seeing only 1 tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`powertop`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/power_management_guide/powertop) to find out what application, device, or other kernel driver, is causing those additional interrupts.